# Optimisation issue in R

Tags: r, optimization

Question relating to optim function in R

I have the following code so far and need to know to input my values of X and T. X is a vector of 10 values and T is vector of 10*2 values relating to the means and variances. I want the output to be in the format of one new value for alpha, mean1, mean2, var1, and var2. Not sure how to get the input data in properly.

I want to run all values of X in this function but only the first row of T (10 values) and im not sure how to do this for T. I have a different function for the 2nd row.

```
R <-runif(10, 0, 1)
S <-1-R
T <-t(cbind(R,S))


X <- runif(10, 25, 35)


Data1 <- function(xy) { 
  alpha <- xy[1]
  mean1 <- xy[2]
  mean2 <- xy[3]
  var1 <- xy[4]
  var2 <- xy[5] 

  -sum(0.5*(((X)-mean1)/var1)^2+alpha*mean1+log(2.5*var1)+log(exp(-alpha*mean1)+exp(-alpha*mean2))*(T))
}
starting_values <- c(0.3, 28, 38, 4, 3)
optim(starting_values, Data1, lower=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), method='L-BFGS-B')
```

also getting the following error code:

```
Error in optim(starting_values, Data1, lower = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B") : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Cheers for any help.

**EDIT**

second function for inclusion

```
0.5*((y1-mean2)/var2)^2+alpha*mean2+log(2.5*var2)+ log(exp(-alpha*mean1)+exp(-alpha*mean2)))*T
```

Ok so to explain as clearly as possible what i want to do. The first function in the original post above takes all 10 values of X one at a time and should take the first row of T data (labelled R here) and im not sure how to do this.

The second function detailed above should again take all 10 values of X in succession and then the second row of data from T (labelled as S below)

all this is then summed together. The five unknown parameters are thusly estimated.

> T

```
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]        [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
R 0.1477715 0.3055021 0.2963543 0.04149945 0.8342484 0.996865333 0.1592568 0.4623762 0.8000778 0.6979342
S 0.8522285 0.6944979 0.7036457 0.95850055 0.1657516 0.003134667 0.8407432 0.5376238 0.1999222 0.3020658
```

**Edit2**

im not getting the same values as ben, even with running the same seed. I have checked that i have all the packages installed and it would appear i do. Im not getting the same final answers and im also unable to call an individual item of opt2$par. Instead of providing reams of output, i will provide the first few lines and the last few.

```
0.3 28 38 4 3 -74.97014 -120.7212 
Loading required package: BB
Loading required package: quadprog
Loading required package: ucminf
Loading required package: Rcgmin
Loading required package: Rvmmin

Attaching package: ‘Rvmmin’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:optimx’:

    optansout

Loading required package: minqa
Loading required package: Rcpp
0.3 28 38 4 3 -74.97014 -120.7212 
0.9501 28 38 4 3 -176.3368 -265.9074 
1.9001 28 38 4 3 -324.7782 -478.4652 
0.9501 28.95 38 4 3 -179.9994 -260.8711 
0.9501 28 38.95 4 3 -176.3366 -283.0445 
0.9501 28 38 4.95 3 -176.7836 -265.9074 
0.9501 28 38 4 3.95 -176.3368 -254.6188
```

.................

```
16.32409 27.86113 38.54337 3.940143 2.504167 -2566.194 -3826.233 
16.32409 27.86113 38.54337 3.940044 2.504167 -2566.194 -3826.233 
16.32409 27.86113 38.54337 3.940093 2.504199 -2566.194 -3826.232 
16.32409 27.86113 38.54337 3.940093 2.504136 -2566.194 -3826.234 
> opt2$par
$par
[1] 16.324085 27.861134 38.543373  3.940093  2.504167

> opt2$par["mean1"]
$<NA>
NULL
```

Comment: without a reproducible example (no data !!) is not simple to answer...

Comment: A few things: 1) You mention `X` and `R`, I don't see `X`. 2) There is no `ln` function in base R, maybe you mean `log`? 3) `optim` needs a function returning a scalar: if `R` is a vector like you say, you have a problem.

Comment: Although you use `R` in your function, it's not an argument of your function? Are you assuming it is a global variable already defined?

Comment: So am i to conclude that this cannot be done using optim and i need to find another method?

Comment: The (current) problem is your function `Data1`. It doesn't work for even your starting values. Try running just `Data1(starting_values)`, it gives an error.

Comment: data1 is arbitrary really, what i need to know is how to get the X and R information in the correct manner to attain the output i specified.

Comment: Despite my answer, I'm still really unclear on the meaning of: "I want to run all values of X in this function but only the first row of T (10 values) and im not sure how to do this for T. I have a different function for the 2nd row." ...

Comment: So do you mean that the objective function is the sum of the two individual values?

Comment: yes so effectively from the first function you would have 10 equations should you write them out and 10 for the second function so the negative sum of these is the key value.

Comment: in order to have `$par` named you need to assign names to your input variable be a *named* numeric variable -- see my `starting_values` assignment below, note the names as well as the numeric values.  As for the numeric differences -- I'm guessing that you are working with a very flat/poorly determined likelihood surface, so even very small changes (like Windows vs MacOS, or different OS versions, or a version of R built with a different compiler), which are normally unimportant, will lead to slight numeric differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A first crack:  I used your code above.  I added `set.seed(101)` at the beginning for reproducibility.

Reformatted the function slightly for clarity, but without changing anything significant, and added a `cat()` statement for debugging purposes:

```
Data1 <- function(xy) {
    alpha <- xy[1]; mean1 <- xy[2]; mean2 <- xy[3]
    var1 <- xy[4]; var2 <- xy[5]

    r1 <- -sum(0.5*((X-mean1)/var1)^2+
           alpha*mean1+
           log(2.5*var1)+
           log(exp(-alpha*mean1)+
               exp(-alpha*mean2))*T[1,])
    r2 <- -sum(0.5*((X-mean2)/var2)^2+
           alpha*mean2+
           log(2.5*var2)+
           log(exp(-alpha*mean1)+exp(-alpha*mean2))*T[2,])

    cat(xy,r1,r2,"\n")
   r1+r2
}
```

A slightly compressed version, that (1) takes advantage of `with` to make the function cleaner; (2) uses R's replication and vector-recycling capabilities

```
Data2 <- function(xy) {
    with(as.list(xy),
    {
       mmat <- rep(c(mean1,mean2),each=ncol(T))
       vmat <- rep(c(var1,var2),each=ncol(T))
       -sum(0.5*((X-mmat)/vmat)^2+
          alpha*mmat+
          log(2.5*vmat)+
          log(exp(-alpha*mean1)+exp(-alpha*mean2))*T)
    })
}
```

Now we need a *named* vector of starting values:

```
 starting_values <- c(alpha=0.3, mean1=28, mean2=38, var1=4, var2=3)
```

Check that the results match:

```
 Data1(starting_values) ##  [1] -195.6913
 Data2(starting_values) ##  [1] -195.6913
```

This fails (but gives us information on how it fails):

```
 optim(par=starting_values, Data1, lower=rep(1e-4,5), method='L-BFGS-B',
     control=list(trace=6))
```

It produces a lot of output, ending with:

```
##  21.29998 27.97361 37.98915 4.011199 3.001 -6014.225 
## 21.29998 27.97361 37.98915 4.011199 2.999 -6014.225 
## 85.29991 27.89318 37.95606 4.04533 3 Inf 
## Error in optim(par = starting_values, Data1, lower = rep(1e-04, 5), 
##    method = "L-BFGS-B",  : 
##     L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

This at least tells you where things went wrong.  I would now try evaluating your expression piece-by-piece to see which bit overflowed.

As a commenter (Justin) in the chat room said,

> your third term log(exp(...) + exp(...)) goes to -Inf very quickly
>   since alpha, mean1 and mean2 are unbounded. exp(-large number * large
>   number) ~ 0

For further debugging, you can:

- try to rearrange the evaluation of your function to avoid overflows
- set upper bounds on some of the parameters to avoid overflows
- have the function test and return very large values rather than Inf in appropriate cases

Unfortunately, `L-BFGS-B` is more fragile than some of the other optimizers, and doesn't allow non-finite values.

Next I tried the `bobyqa` optimizer from the `optimx` package, which allows bounds *and* handles non-finite values (and is a derivative-free method, which in general tend to be slightly slower but more robust than the derivative-based methods): it seems to work OK, although I don't know if the answers are sensible or not.

```
library(optimx)
opt2 <- optimx(par=starting_values, 
      Data1, lower=rep(1e-4,5), method='bobyqa')
opt3 <- optimx(par=starting_values, 
      Data2, lower=rep(1e-4,5), method='bobyqa')
```

Looks OK (provided this is a sensible answer, which I don't know).

```
> opt2$par
$par
    alpha     mean1     mean2      var1      var2 
16.330752 27.815324 38.497483  3.894179  2.447219 

> opt3$par
$par
    alpha     mean1     mean2      var1      var2 
16.330900 27.820813 38.491290  3.887975  2.456052
```

Note that the answers are slightly different (by about 0.5% in the case of var2), which suggests that the fit may be slightly unstable/the surface may be quite flat.  (`Data1` and Data2 are supposed to give **identical** answers, and do so for the starting values, but I guess the order of operations makes them give very slightly different answers for some inputs -- or I screwed up somewhere ...)

To extract an individual component from this fit, e.g. `mean1`, use vector indexing:

```
opt3$par["mean1"]  ## 27.820813
```

Comment: Thanks for having a shot ben, i made an edit to the original question with something i just finished with. Just a little unsure about a couple of issues which i outlined

Comment: the alpha value is not sensible and placing an upper limit on it results in strange values for the other parameters. So attempting to constrain all the values means the process does not complete.

Comment: Well, then either (1) there are multiple minima and the optimizer is finding the wrong one, or (2) there's something else wrong (a mistake in your statement of the problem, a bug in the likelihood function ...)  Not sure what else I can do to help.

Comment: cheers ben, appreciate the comment, just going through everything now to see if i can spot any errors.

Comment: Couple of quick questions on the above. 1. If i want to get all the values from each iteration that contribute to the total likelihood value (ie -6014.225 in bens answer), how do i do it? 2. When i run my code im getting two values for likelihood (ie one for r1 and one for r2), despite the fact r1+r2 is in the code, is it possible to remedy this? Thanks

Comment: these questions aren't as clear as they might be ... (1) do you want the intermediate results of the optimization stored?  do you want the components of the likelihood function returned?  You can print multiple values using `cat()` or `sprintf()`; you can return a set of values as a numeric vector or a list (but `optim()` requires an objective function that returns a single value). (2) I can't diagnose what's wrong without seeing it.  You might post a follow-up question for #1, if you can ...

Comment: I was going to recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for question #2, but I see that it's intended for *working* code.  Does your function look *exactly* like my `Data1` above ... ?

Comment: Managed to solve the above, cheers. Regarding the final output via opt2$par and $par, how is it possible to reference individual entities from this in another funcction? For example, if one wanted to call mean1 (27.815), how would it be done?

Comment: Cheers Ben, im not quite getting the same final values as you (in the same ballpark though. I also notice that when i call opt2$par, there are no headers for each item (alpha, mean1, etc). I have used your code exactly and the same seed but still there is a difference. I have provided some output at Edit2 above.